# Bring the browser to the front of all window/application in php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am developing a page in php and javascript and I need to be able to notify the user if they didn't submit the page within 10 minutes, for this to work I need to bring the browser in front of all other applications running on the machine.

Is there any possibility that this can be done?

Comment: I can only imagine the havoc this would wreak if this were possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, without html5 and that too user confirming the security popup, its impossible to bring the window on to front, atleast on IE it used to show a blink when there is a popup, but in chrome each runs on a seperate process and you wont even notice a blink too.

and well its not a mobile though, where you can use push notifications from the server to bring your app back

Answer (score 1):

Luckily you usually cannot do that. :)

PHP is a server-side language so it cannot do something like this for obvious reasons.

All you *can* do is call `window.focus();` in JavaScript and hope it's not disabled in the user's browser - in Firefox it is disabled by default for example.

Comment: You could also flash text in the title bar of the document like Google does with chat in the browser and hope the user sees it.  I think window.document.title is the way to access that.

Comment: or with the users agreement html 5 notifications https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_of_notifications81?lang=en

Comment: Not working with Firefox 43.0.1 : `window.focus()` executes, but the window does not come to the front.

Answer (score 0):

If you're users are willing to install a script you could try [growl](http://ajaxian.com/archives/growls-for-windows-and-a-web-notification-api). You could then use the javascript api to create some notification.